# I am encountering a bug when trying to store the url for my uploaded image in firestore

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

My app runs well except for the fact that it creates a bug when trying to store the url for an uploaded image.

FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field eventImgUrl)

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(eventImage) {

        const uploadImage = storage.ref(`EventImages/${values.eventName}`).put(eventImage);
        uploadImage.on('state_changed',
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            },
            () => {
                storage.ref('EventImages').child(values.eventName).getDownloadURL().then(url =>{
                    console.log(url);
                    setUrl(url);
                })

            }
        );
        }

        dbref.add({
            eventName: values.eventName,
            eventVenue: values.eventVenue,
            eventAddress: values.eventAddress,
            eventCategory: values.eventCategory,
            eventOrganizer: values.eventOrganizer,
            eventPhone: values.eventPhone,
            eventEmail: values.eventEmail,
            eventDetails: values.eventDetails,
            eventDate: selectedDate.toDateString(),
            eventTime: selectedDate.toLocaleTimeString(),
            eventImgUrl: eventImageUrl
        }).then((docRef) => {
            console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
            setValues('');
            setImg('');
            setUrl('');
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });

    }
```

I want to store the img url into my created document. I'm using a hook for the url as : const [eventImageUrl, setUrl] = React.useState();

Comment: can you `console.log(eventImageUrl)`

Comment: I already checked it at **console.log(url);**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you

```
console.log(url)
```

is there any value? Now try to console.log your

```
eventImageUrl
```

before you add it to db... What it says? I believe it will be undefined. You can also try to hardcode the url

```
eventImgUrl: "www.test.test"
```

Does it work?

If so you know that the problem is in your eventImageUrl hook. To help you more we  need full code

**UPDATE**

Try this

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
if (eventImage) {
    const uploadImage = storage.ref(`EventImages/${values.eventName}`)
    uploadImage.put(eventImage).then(() => {
        storage.ref('EventImages').child(values.eventName).getDownloadURL().then(url => {
            dbref.add({
                eventName: values.eventName,
                eventVenue: values.eventVenue,
                eventAddress: values.eventAddress,
                eventCategory: values.eventCategory,
                eventOrganizer: values.eventOrganizer,
                eventPhone: values.eventPhone,
                eventEmail: values.eventEmail,
                eventDetails: values.eventDetails,
                eventDate: selectedDate.toDateString(),
                eventTime: selectedDate.toLocaleTimeString(),
                eventImgUrl: url
            }).then((docRef) => {
                console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
                setValues('');
                setImg('');
                setUrl('');
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
            });
        })
    })

}
}
```

Comment: It works when I manually enter the url which is : **https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/envy-hxxdini.appspot.com/o/EventImages%2FERD%20-%20Timetable.jpg?alt=media&token=a92790f2-7981-49f2-aa77-714a1dfcb47c**

Comment: Please answer all questions I’ve asked

Comment: console.log(url) doesn't show anything in my browser console

Comment: @Carl Try to change your code with my updated answer

Comment: It didn't work sorry .. It just uploads the image ie the code doesn't run after the upload is complete

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that `eventImageUrl` is undefined.  That means you never assigned it a value.  In the code you've shown here, we can't even see where it was declared.

You will have to debug your code and make sure that `eventImageUrl` contains the value you expect.

Comment: It says the value contained in the eventImgUrl is unsupported.

Comment: I declared it using a hook : [eventImageUrl, setUrl] = React.useState();

Comment: Read the error message carefully.  It says the value is undefined.

Comment: The error says : **FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field eventImgUrl)**

Comment: Do you see the part where it says the unsupported value is "undefined"?

Comment: As I said, you will have to debug your app to make sure that eventImageUrl contains the value you expect.

Comment: console doesn't print anything .. But when i manually enter the url it works

Answer (score 0):

the error is from your `const [eventImageUrl, setUrl] = React.useState()`
Change `eventImageUrl` to `url`. that seems to be your problem

Comment: It still produces the same error **FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field eventImgUrl)**

Comment: what does console.log(url) print?

Comment: console doesn't print anything .. But when i manually enter the url it works